# Display websites like a screen reader perceives it?

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers

I stumbled over the (discontinued?) chrome extensions [Chrome Shades](https://code.google.com/p/google-axs-chrome/), which displays a website the way a screen reader perceives it:

- Images are replaced with their `alt` texts
- Contents are displayed/hidden according to CSS (`display:none` and `visibility:hidden`) and WAI-ARIA (`aria-hidden="true"`) attributes and states
- Form labels are checked upon correct relationships to input fields
- `title` Attributes are displayed
- etc.

Sadly, the extension seems to be discontinued, and the current version makes my Chrome crash.

Is there any other useful way for doing this? To be clear: I'm not asking about different tools doing different things (like e.g. Firefox' [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) which allows e.g. to display the `alt` attribute of images), but some sort of an all-in-one tool which converts a visual website into a more or less linear representation.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say be wary of anything that boast a "just run this and know what a blind individual experiences", however, I know the author of the extension, I wish there was a better disclaimer.

At the bottom of the manual, it mentions that some of the stuff it does can be done via just disabling CSS - which you don't need an extension for. A popular tool is [WebAIM's WAVE](http://wave.webaim.org/), which does test against the [WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag), versus ChromeShades that look at the easy-to-hit targets.

Besides WAVE, you should be doing your own checking, because true automatic (ChromeShades is not one) can only hit between [17 and 25% of WCAG 2.0](http://www.karlgroves.com/2012/09/15/accessibility-testing-what-can-be-tested-and-how/). It is good to use a checklist, which [WebAIM has one](http://webaim.org/standards/wcag/checklist). I believe the W3C has one at the link above.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned that I'm already an experienced accessibility consultant, and I know many of the tools you describe. For a very quick overview it would just be useful to have something like ChromeShades that displays most obvious problems with just one click (instead of having to activate different small tools for doing it) and also makes it easy for customers to get a feeling for the problems of his website.

Comment: I use three tools personally. First I do my own check, which I would describe kind of like what ChromeShades does, but it is manual. If I am feeling lazy or think there is something kind of missing - I use Wave. If I need to officially put my stamp on something, I use my company's checklists. The point I am making is you should not be using one-click solutions. The closest thing I'd suggest would be WAVE